# WAMP server 2.2 + gettext with Arabic on windows 64 bit doesn't work

Tags: php, windows, wamp, gettext, arabic

I'm using WAMP server 2.2 (php ver 5.53.13) (mysql ver 5.5.24) on my development machine (localhost)

I'm using gettext .. my po & mo files generated by poeditor.com

I have to support two languages (Arabic + English)

the php code :

```
$locale = "ar_QA";
if (isset($_GET["locale"])) $locale = $_GET["locale"];
putenv("LC_ALL=$locale");
putenv('LANG='.$locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);

bindtextdomain("messages", "./locale");
bind_textdomain_codeset("messages", "UTF-8");
textdomain("messages");
```

The folder structure is like the following:

[image]

the LC_MESSAGES folders contain (messages.po + messages.mo) files

On my online hosting server (linux  os) both Arabic + English is working fine but on my development machine (windows server 2008 64 bit) English is working but Arabic is not working

Answer (score 0):

Might be too late but I was having similar issues until I enabled "short open tag" in my WAMP php settings